# Equivalent vs equal. When to use what?

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

When do you use equal and when equivalent?

Why do I see on this site: (this is a random formula taken from this site):

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}F_X(x; \mu, \sigma^2)
=\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)
= \phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\frac{-1}{\sigma}
= -\left[\frac{1}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]$

And why not:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}F_X(x; \mu, \sigma^2)
\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)
\equiv \phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\frac{-1}{\sigma}
\equiv -\left[\frac{1}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]$

And:

$f(x) = x^2 = x * x$

or

$f(x) = x^2 \equiv x * x$

When to use what?

Comment: The notation $=$ is somewhat overloaded, so on the bright side that means it's harder to go wrong with it. On the other hand, though, that makes it harder to spot when it's really wrong to use, and you should rather use $\cong$ or $\simeq$.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes people use $=$ for values, and $\equiv$ for functions. That is, $f(x)=0$ means that $x$ is a root of $f$, whereas $f(x)\equiv 0$ means that $f$ is identically 0.

Comment: So if I follow your argument, this derivative above can be written with equivalent

Comment: And then you have $f(x):= 0$, which is used by some to _define_ $f$ to be the zero function.